# Sqlite Distinct Query From -To, To - From

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have following data:
me = my_userid;
    Table: Message 
    message_id | message_from | message_to
    1          | me           | user
    2          | user         | me

Running query gives two rows (SELECT DISTINCT message_from,message_to FROM Message WHERE message_from ='"+me+"' OR message_to ='"+me+"'");

Used OR because my id can be in from(when sending) or in TO (when other user sends me message)
-- This returns two rows however i want it to return one row because if you switch to - from you get same ids, So how can this be done in the query. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min()` and `max()` as *scalar* functions:

```
select distinct min(message_from, message_to) as m1, max(message_from, message_to) as m2
from message
where message_from ='"+me+"' OR message_to ='"+me+"'"
```

These are equivalent to `least()` and `greatest()` in other databases.